# How to set argument app for appcmd in the same way for images ltsc2016 and lt2019?

Tags: docker, powershell, iis-8, docker-for-windows

I'm trying to use same dockerfile to build the images ltsc2016 and ltsc2019, but i'm stuck on the appcmd command.

For **ltsc2016** only works if quotes are `'`:

```
RUN c:\windows\system32\inetsrv\appcmd set app 'Default Web Site/' /enabledProtocols:"http"
```

If i change to double quotes:

RUN c:\windows\system32\inetsrv\appcmd set app "Default Web Site/" /enabledProtocols:"http"

> Failed to process input: The parameter 'Web' must begin with a / or - (HRESULT=80070057).

For image **ltsc2019** only works if images are `"`:

```
RUN c:\windows\system32\inetsrv\appcmd set app "Default Web Site/" /enabledProtocols:"http"
```

But if i set equal to ltsc2019 i get:

> to process input: The parameter 'Web' must begin with a / or - (HRESULT=80070057).

Odd thing, enabledProtocols works fine in both images using same character for quote.

This looks like a bug on appcmd.exe but i haven't be able to circumvent it.

Any ideas?

The dockerfile:

```
# escape=`

#from ms samples https://github.com/microsoft/dotnet-framework-docker/blob/main/src/wcf/4.8/windowsservercore-ltsc2022/Dockerfile

ARG REPO=mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/framework/aspnet
ARG OS_VERSION=ltsc2022
FROM $REPO:4.8-windowsservercore-${OS_VERSION}

# Install Windows components required for WCF service hosted on IIS
RUN dism /Online /Quiet /Enable-Feature /All /FeatureName:WCF-HTTP-Activation45 /FeatureName:WCF-TCP-Activation45 /FeatureName:IIS-WebSockets /FeatureName:IIS-BasicAuthentication

# Enable net.tcp protocol for default web site on IIS
RUN c:\windows\system32\inetsrv\appcmd set app "Default Web Site/" /enabledProtocols:"http"

EXPOSE 80

WORKDIR C:\inetpub\wwwroot

COPY . .
```

Comment: What if you put every commands in a `.ps1` file and then call `powershell -file some.ps1` in your `Dockerfile`? Maybe the bad guy is Docker.

Comment: Just some general pointers: If `'` quotes work, the implication is that PowerShell is being used to execute the command line. If only `"` quotes work, `cmd.exe` is implied (or the use of no shell at all).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`@mklement0` gave the right pointer, the command was executed with `cmd.exe` on one image and with `powershell` on other and that was causing the different behavior regarding quotes.

So, just had to force `RUN` command to use `powershell` always, by adding the following command at start:

```
SHELL ["powershell", "-Command"]
```

The complete dockerfile:

```
# escape=`

#from ms samples https://github.com/microsoft/dotnet-framework-docker/blob/main/src/wcf/4.8/windowsservercore-ltsc2022/Dockerfile

ARG REPO=mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/framework/aspnet
ARG OS_VERSION=ltsc2022
FROM $REPO:4.8-windowsservercore-${OS_VERSION}

#force the use of powershell on all builds
SHELL ["powershell", "-Command"]

# Install Windows components required for WCF service hosted on IIS
RUN dism /Online /Quiet /Enable-Feature /All /FeatureName:WCF-HTTP-Activation45 /FeatureName:WCF-TCP-Activation45 /FeatureName:IIS-WebSockets /FeatureName:IIS-BasicAuthentication

# Enable net.tcp protocol for default web site on IIS
RUN c:\windows\system32\inetsrv\appcmd set app "Default Web Site/" /enabledProtocols:"http"

EXPOSE 80

WORKDIR C:\inetpub\wwwroot

COPY . .
```

Comment: Calling it `msdos` is an old habit that didn't die. just updated.